# Changing the offset of edi vs changing the value at the address?

Tags: arrays, loops, assembly, masm, irvine32

So, this is maybe a bit of a specific question, but my ASM assignment is to create a 10 element array that adds the first element to the last one and places the result in the first element of the array, then the second element with the 9th one and places the result in the second element of the array, etc.

a0 + a9 ---> a0
a1 + a8 ---> a1, etc.

The same procedure should subtract the first element from the 10th element and place the result in the 10th element.  Subtract the 2nd element from the 9th one and place the result in the 9th element, etc. Like this:

So that if you input 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0, as an example, the program output should be 1, 11, 11, 11, 11, 1, 3, 5, 7, -1.

I am at a complete loss here, I'm not sure how to go back and forth moving around the OFFSET in the edi as well as changing the value at that address ?

```
 INCLUDE c:\Irvine\Irvine32.inc

 ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword

 .data      ;// write your data in this section
    intarray DWORD ?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?
     msg2 BYTE "The processed array:", 0
     endl BYTE 0dh, 0ah, 0
     count DWORD 0
     x DWORD 0
     y DWORD 0


 .code      
    main proc
    mov eax, 0 ; zeros out the eax register
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF intarray 
    mov edi, OFFSET intarray; 
    mov edx, OFFSET endl; moves the location of endl to edx

 L1:
     call ReadInt ; takes user integer input for the eax register
     mov [edi], eax; moves value from the eax register to the edi
     add edi, TYPE DWORD; increments the address 
     Loop L1; restarts first loop


     mov edx, OFFSET msg2 ; moves msg2 to the edx register
     call WriteString ; Writes the value in the edx register to the screen
     mov edx, OFFSET endl ; moves endl (line break) to the edx register
     call WriteString ; prints the value in the edx register to the screen


    mov ecx, LENGTHOF intarray/2 ;
      L3: 

     Loop L3 ; restarts the loop

     mov ecx, LENGTHOF intarray ;
     mov edi, OFFSET intarray; 

      L4:
          mov eax, edi;
          call WriteInt 
          add edi, TYPE DWORD; increments the address 

      loop L4

     invoke ExitProcess,0
 main endp
 end main
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read both array elements in registers, then perform the `add` or `sub` at the requested end of the array.
Advance the pointer in EDI but lower ECX twice as fast.

```
    mov edi, OFFSET intarray
    mov ecx, 9            ;10 elements in the array
Again:
    mov eax, [edi]
    mov ebx, [edi+ecx*4]
    add [edi], ebx
    sub [edi+ecx*4], eax
    add edi, 4
    sub ecx, 2
    jnb Again
```

Comment: This is not the direction I was going with, but when I tried it this way I at least got real numbers, not addresses. The output was not correct for me though, with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0 I got 1,5,1,4,5,6,7,8,9,-1

Comment: You're scaling ecx by 4 when you use it, so you should probably only decrease it by 2 (or initialize it to `9*4` and remove the `*4` in the effective addresses, which might make it easier to read).  Otherwise the loop only runs 2 iterations (ecx=9 and ecx=1).  @Io-stream: If you didn't work that out yourself, try it.

Comment: Okay! So my final code is
     mov edi, OFFSET intarray
         mov ecx, 9            ;10 elements in the array
     Again:
         mov eax, [edi]
         mov ebx, [edi+ecx*4]
         add [edi], ebx
         sub [edi+ecx*4], eax
         add edi, 4
         sub ecx, 2
         jnb Again
and it works! Thank you guys so much!

Comment: @PeterCordes It was a typo, writing `sub ecx,8`. I fixed it.